# Is there software to tell what kind of hardware I have so I can find drivers for it?

Tags: hardware-detection

Maybe I'm just lazy, but I really don't want to open this computer up and look. I'd like to know the type of wireless network card I have, but CPU-Z doesn't tell me. I need drivers for my wireless network card so the Device Manager just files it under Other Devices -> Network Controller.

Comment: related (if not even duplicate): http://superuser.com/questions/97238/windows-equivalent-for-lspci

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Device Manager to get the vendor and device IDs for the various PCI and USB devices on your system, and then a quick Google search will help you find the make and model.

Comment: Yeah but that won't help me. My bad... I was making the assumption that people knew that I couldn't get that information from the Device Manager. Please edit your answer or delete it.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat: You can *always* get IDs, even from unknown devices.

Comment: Under Details I see a drop down list with information. None of them say anything about VendorIDs. One does say Device Instance ID. Is that it?

Comment: Dunno. Post what it is and I can tell you (I don't have a Windows machine around to verify the name).

Comment: @Ignacio... I think it might have worked. I'm downloading drivers based off a google search. Here is the Device Instance ID: `PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4318&SUBSYS_044914E4&REV_02\4&13699180&0&3848`

Comment: Yep, that's the right one. Broadcom 4318.

Comment: WIN!!! Thanks Ignacio. Found the drivers... Everything's good. I have wifi :D.

Answer (score 2):

Start -> Control Panel -> System ICON -> Hardware -> Device Manager - Look under Network Adapters.

Comment: +1 for putting me in the right direction. Ignacio was able to get me where I needed though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that software is able to tell you what make or model number your wireless card is. It can only tell you what chip-set it uses. Fortunately that is usually enough to get working drivers for the device.

I would boot a linux live cd and run lspci -v from the command line to get the hardware details.

[System Information for Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html) appears to do the trick from windows. I tried the freeware version.

https://superuser.com/questions/97238/windows-equivalent-for-lspci