# how to find wireless adapter driver if I do not know the manufacturer?

Tags: drivers, wireless-adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there software to tell what kind of hardware I have so I can find drivers for it?](https://superuser.com/questions/234078/is-there-software-to-tell-what-kind-of-hardware-i-have-so-i-can-find-drivers-for)

Problem: I need a wireless adapter driver for my formatted HP ProBook 4410s on running Vista Business.

I installed everything on the Driver CD that HP provide but the Device Manager still say cannot find driver. It also does not show the mnufacturer so I cannot get it from their website.

Is there a generic wireless adapter driver I can use?

Other than solving this problem, I am primarily interested in knowing if it is possible to query the adapter for the MAC ID and subsequently know the make and model and manufacturer without the driver in the first place. Any help please. Thanks =)

EDIT: Should have searched in SuperUser instead of ServerFault.

Comment: You could obtains a Ubuntu Live CD and then in a terminal run `sudo lshw -C network`. This will print out the chipset used. From there you can download the appropriate driver (e.g. Ralink).

Comment: Yes it is... my ServerFault posts gets migrated to SuperUser and vice versa. Most of the time. I have a problem. Now, should you post that link as answer please?

Answer (score 0):

The wireless card's MAC address may well be written on it (if you can easily remove it) or on the computer (if it's integrated or difficult to access, as on most labtops). Have a look for it on or near the serial number stickers/plates/etchings that are usually somewhere on the underside or back of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address itself (which can be obtained by **ipconfig /all** on the Commmand Line) will tell you the manufacturer, but unfortunately not the model.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the command doesn't list hardware without drivers.